# Android App: Connecting to GATT server using UUIDs

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

I'm trying to connect to Bleno Periphecal GATT server from my android app.

The GATT Server has Custom Service and Characteristic with unique UUIDs.

How can I pinpoint connect to this server and send some text?

The minimum SDK is 21, and target SDK is 24, so old BluetoothLE Scanning method is deprecated, and now I need to use BluetoothLEScanner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For connecting Ble simply use this method pass mac address of your BTdevice.

```
 private boolean connectGatt(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }

    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    return mBluetoothGatt.connect();
}
```

and you should register a callback to know connection is success or not.

```
 private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            //bluetooth is connected so discover services
            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            //Bluetooth is disconnected
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
          // services are discoverd 
        }

        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
       
    }
};
```

once services are discoverd you can write or read from the services.

to write to a service use this method

```
 private boolean writeRXCharacteristic(byte[] value) {
    BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(/*Place service UUID*/);
    if (RxService == null) {
        //Service not supported
        return false;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic RxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(/*RX_CHAR_UUID*/);
    if (RxChar == null) {
        // service not supported
        return false;
    }
     RxChar.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        RxChar.setValue(arr);
        return mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(RxChar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Where did iGatt,iChar, and arr come from? I'm not familiar with those things. Do I need to initialize these values in writeRXCharacteristic function? Also when should i call writeRXCharacteristic function?

Comment: @ToshihiroMSakurai did you find out what are the arr, iGatt and iChar values mean?

Comment: @Keselme arr is byte array you want to send, iGatt is your Gatt service which you'll get on connection, ichar is BluetoothGattCharacteristic.

Comment: @Jayanth thank you. When I do `writeCharacteristics`, should `onCharacteristicWrite` be triggered or any other callback?

Comment: onCharacteristicWrite will be called